# "READ" constant in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax

I found the following PL/SQL code but I am unable to find it as a valid constant declaration from Oracle documentation.

Can anyone explain me what this means?

```
create or replace package file_security authid current_user is
  READ  constant pls_integer := 1;
  WRITE constant pls_integer := 2;
  EXEC  constant pls_integer := 4;

  procedure grant_permission(
    p_file_path  in varchar2,
    p_grantee    in varchar2,
    p_permission in pls_integer  
  );

end file_security;
```

Comment: The package declares three constants (called `READ`, `WRITE` and `EXEC`) and a function, which would supposedly accept a binary mask of those constants as its third parameter. Which bit exactly you need explained?

Comment: Exactly because READ, WRITE and EXEC are 3 reserved words. Can they be used as normal variable/constant names?

Comment: none of those words are reserved in Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm#BABHJHFE, they "have a special meaning to Oracle but are not reserved words and so can be redefined"

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi for the prompt reply. Also, I found this code: `HTP.title (.Account Information.);`. What is the meaning of (. and .) in PLSQL?

Comment: Please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package declares three constants (called `READ`, `WRITE` and `EXEC`) and a function, which would supposedly accept a binary mask of those constants as its third parameter.

None of those words are [reserved](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm#BABGHAFH) in Oracle, they "have a special meaning to Oracle but are not reserved words and so can be redefined"